# How do you pass UiPath variables between sequences and workflows?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

Variables in UiPath are visible only within the activity block in which they are declared, and they are definitely not visible in other workflows or sequences.

If I have a variable and I want to use that variable's value in another sequence or workflow, how do I access it?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, variable scope in UiPath is limited to the activity in which a variable is defined, and of course, the sub-activities nested within.

### Pass Data with UiPath Arguments

To pass a variable from one sequence to the next, you must use [UiPath arguments](https://www.rpacertified.com/2021/06/11/how-to-pass-uipath-arguments-example.html).

If you want to pass a variable from Sequence A to Sequence B, you configure an argument of the same data type in Sequence B using the Arguments tab, which is right next to the variables tab.

[image]

### UiPath Argument Directions

There are three possible [argument directions](https://www.rpacertified.com/2020/09/09/var-argument-directions.html) you can configure:

- To pass a variable from Sequence A to Sequence B, sequence B will define an argument with an `in` direction.
- To pass a variable from Sequence B to Sequence A, sequence B will define an argument with an `out` direction.
- If you want to combine both, there is an in/out direction as well.

### Map UiPath Arguments to Variable

With the argument is defined, the point where Sequence A invokes Sequence B will have an indicator that you must `Import Uipath Arguments`. Click on this button and map the argument defined in Sequence B to the variable used in Sequence A.

[image]

When you are finished, you will have successfully [passed a UiPath argument](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Pass-UiPath-Arguments-Example-Tutorial) from one sequence to another.